# Testing for a block in a certain radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making an arrow that explodes when it hits anything, but I need a way to testfor all blocks within a radius of 2 blocks to see if they're air or not. The only problem is, I dont know how.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than testing for air blocks, why not use the inGround datatag for this:

First create a scoreboard:

```
/scoreboard objectives add arrow dummy
```

Then, run these 2 commands on a fast clock:

```
/scoreboard players add @e[type=Arrow] arrow 1 {inGround:true}
/execute @e[score_arrow_min=1] ~ ~ ~ summon Creeper ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:1,ignited:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:999999}],powered:true}
```

Happy exploding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [testforblocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#testforblocks) command to easily check for whether an area contains only air or not, but it would require a designated area which must remain empty at all times.  If this is on a server, you may want to encase this region in bedrock and "hide" it underground somewhere.  As an example of usage, you would want to type

```
/testforblocks 0 60 0 3 63 3 30 70 30
```

if the empty area was (0,60,0) to (3,63,3) and the area to check for emptiness was (30,70,30) to (33,73,33).  Technically speaking, the two regions could be switched without any noticeable effect on the result.  I would imagine that in your particular case, you'd want something more along the lines of

```
/execute @e[type=Arrow] ~ ~ ~ /testforblocks 0 60 0 3 63 3 ~-1 ~-1 ~-1
```

along with whatever else you plan to do.  Hope that helps!